# Proper way to migrate a user profile?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I've taken a look at a couple solutions here and other sites in regards to migrating a profile,but they just don't seem to apply in my situation.

I have this current script that deletes user profiles using the following line:

```
Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $cn -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object { $_.LocalPath.split('\')[-1] -eq $Profile } | Remove-CimInstance
```

So I was thinking... Since the above line deletes the selected profile of my choice, can I copy it to another system?

I feel like in theory it should work. All im really doing is grabbing the profile object from the class and removing all it's content, right? I tried piping it to `copy-item`, but then I'm stuck. I'm just not sure what would be the next step in regards to where to copy it to. Back to the namespace in wmi, to it's appropriate class? Is this even possible?

I would like to mention I am on a very strict network environment/domain which doesn't allow me to use fancy tools to copy the profile over.

Comment: Copying a user profile is much more complicated than that.

Comment: What's the proper way of going about it? Copying the registry keys? Ntuser.data file? What all entails a profile

Answer (score 0):

I think you're expecting that the profile is a self-contained set of files, when it is not. There are dependencies elsewhere in a system that rely on the profile folder being there, and there are aspects of the profile that are dependent on being in a specific computer/OS. There are multiple inter-related interdependencies that will break when a profile folder is just taken from one place and dropped into another place.

While specific aspects of a profile can be migrated using tools or utilities built for this purpose, these will nearly always involve more than simple movement of the files from one place to the other.

The proper way to migrate a profile is to list the specific aspects of the profile you wish to migrate, and find the specific methods those aspects support for migration, and use those.

Comment: So, does the win32_userprofile class not hold all the information thats needed? When i remove a profile using this method, everything from reg keys, to files are deleted that correlate to the user themselves. Am i not able to tap into the same content and just export?